# Is there a space? Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, spacing

Im looking for a way to say, if there is no space in this value then say hey there is no space, if there is then change that space to a + and evaluate it...

I got the evaluation correct but can't get it to go to that step when a space is found. The code keeps getting stuck on ""if not value.isspace():"" even when there is a space present.

```
    for value in nulls_measure:
        try:
            value = value.strip()
            nulls_measure[nulls_measure.index(value)] = float(value) if value else 0
        except ValueError:
            if not value.isspace():
                spacing_error = tk.Tk()
                spacing_error.wm_title("Spacing Error")
                tk.Label(spacing_error,text="Please make sure there is spacing in abrasive length.").grid(row=0,column=0)
                tk.Button(spacing_error,text="     OK     ",command=spacing_error.destroy).grid(row=1,column=0)
                raise ValueError("Space Error")

            else:
                try:
                    nulls_measure[nulls_measure.index(value)] = eval(value.replace(" ","+"))
                except ValueError:
                    numbers_only = tk.Tk()
                    numbers_only.wm_title("Letter Error")
                    tk.Label(numbers_only,text="Please make sure inputs are numbers, not letters.").grid(row=0,column=0)
                    tk.Button(numbers_only,text="     OK     ",command=numbers_only.destroy).grid(row=1,column=0)
                    raise ValueError("Letter Error")
```

Comment: `value = value.strip()` removes all space from your items in the list on the left and right sides of that item. I see nothing in your code that indicates you should ever see a space. The next thing you are doing is converting the value to a float and this also will have no spaces in the results. So why do you think you should ever see a space?

Comment: @Mike-SMT Inputs are like '15', '16', '45 7/8', '46 1/8'. So as far as I know strip is getting rid of the quotations, The method strip() returns a copy of the string in which all chars have been stripped from the beginning and the end of the string (default whitespace characters). Not whats in the middle. So the try step gets rid of quotations and attempts to turn the value into a float or 0 if there is nothing there. Except for 45 7/8 and 46 1/8. Then if the value is not spaced ex 457/8 raise error and popup saying theres no space. If there is space then replace space with a + and evaluate.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Never mind, I got it. changed it to `if " " in value;` instead of `value.isspace()` apparently isspace() only works when its only spaces not spaces and whatever else may be there.

Comment: Letto strip is not getting rid of quotes. The only thing strip does is delete any spaces from the left and right of a given string. example: `"   some string   ".strip()`  == `"some string"`.

Comment: Yeah I see your point after messing about with it for a while, but it shouldn't have whitespace at beginning or end either so I'm gonna keep it.

Comment: That is fine. You can keep `strip()`, I would. My point is you should not expect to see any space ever from a list of numbers while using strip.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike-SMT Never mind, I got it. changed it to if " " in value; instead of value.isspace() apparently isspace() only works when its only spaces not spaces and whatever else may be there. – letto4135